# Как сделать метки на яндекс картах, исходя из адреса, а не координат?

Tags: карты, yandex-maps-api

Нашел в документации апи функции для простановки меток на карту, но они задаются географическими координатами.
Я хочу, чтобы метка определяла координаты сама, исходя из адреса.

Это возможно? не могу найти в документации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Нужно использовать функции [геокодера](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/About.xml). Есть [примеры](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/examples/geocoder_examples.xml).