# Задать для метки на яндекс карте не координаты, а адрес

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть такая вот карта:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
var adress_needed = 'Москва';

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
        zoom: 10,
        controls: []
    });


    ymaps.geocode(adress_needed, {
        results: 1
    }).then(function (res) {
        myMap.controls.add('zoomControl', { left: 5, top: 5 });
        var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
            coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
            bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');

        myMap.setBounds(bounds, {
            checkZoomRange: true
        });
      
        var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.752577,37.632134], {
            
        }, {
            iconImageHref: 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/--ddYKXz6fpc/Uh1NrRYLtVI/AAAAAAAAAPA/Bd16ChUzC2Q/s1600/home-icon.png',
            iconImageSize: [50, 40],
            iconImageOffset: [0, -50],
        });  

        var myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([55.52, 37.622093], {
            
        }, {
            iconImageHref: 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/--ddYKXz6fpc/Uh1NrRYLtVI/AAAAAAAAAPA/Bd16ChUzC2Q/s1600/home-icon.png',
            iconImageSize: [50, 40],
            iconImageOffset: [0, -50],
        });           

              
        myMap.geoObjects
          .add(myPlacemark)
          .add(myPlacemark1);
    });
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&amp;lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>


<div id="map"></div>
```

Создаю метки:

```
var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([X0,Y0], ...

... 

var myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([X1, Y1], {

... 

var myPlacemarkN = new ymaps.Placemark([XN, YN], {
```

**Вопрос:** Можно ли как-то задавать не координаты X,Y , а вводить адрес, например, *"Москва, улица Заречная, 2"* и т.д (`myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark("Москва, улица Заречная, 2", ...`  - так не работает)?

*Карта со всеми метками должна отображаться сразу после загрузки.*

**P.S:** Этот вопрос [Как сделать метки на яндекс картах, исходя из адреса, а не координат?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/78964/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82) смотрела уже. Примеры не поняла. Запрос вставлять вместо адреса что ли?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример создания метки по адресу, вводите адрес и создается метка на карте после нажатия на кнопку (Ваш пример редактировал).

Согласно апи яндекс карт ищутся ближайшие координаты по введенному адресу.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);
var adress_needed = 'Москва';

var add = function() {
  addToMap(document.getElementById("address").value);
  addToMap(document.getElementById("address1").value);
  addToMap(document.getElementById("address2").value);
  addToMap(document.getElementById("address3").value);
  addToMap(document.getElementById("address4").value);
};

var addToMap = function(inputAdress) {
  ymaps.geocode(inputAdress, { //ищем по нужному адресу
    boundedBy: myMap.getBounds(),
    results: 1
  }).then(function(res) {
    myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects.get(0));
  });
};


var myMap;

function init() {
  myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
    zoom: 10,
    controls: []
  });

  ymaps.geocode(adress_needed, {
    results: 1
  }).then(function(res) {
    myMap.controls.add('zoomControl', {
      left: 5,
      top: 5
    });
    var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0),
      coords = firstGeoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
      bounds = firstGeoObject.properties.get('boundedBy');

    myMap.setBounds(bounds, {
      checkZoomRange: true
    });

    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.752577, 37.632134], {

    }, {
      iconImageHref: 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/--ddYKXz6fpc/Uh1NrRYLtVI/AAAAAAAAAPA/Bd16ChUzC2Q/s1600/home-icon.png',
      iconImageSize: [50, 40],
      iconImageOffset: [0, -50],
    });

    var myPlacemark1 = new ymaps.Placemark([55.52, 37.622093], {

    }, {
      iconImageHref: 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/--ddYKXz6fpc/Uh1NrRYLtVI/AAAAAAAAAPA/Bd16ChUzC2Q/s1600/home-icon.png',
      iconImageSize: [50, 40],
      iconImageOffset: [0, -50],
    });

    myMap.geoObjects
      .add(myPlacemark)
      .add(myPlacemark1);
  });
  
  add();
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?load=package.standard&amp;lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>
  <input id="address" value="Москва, улица Заречная, 2" /> <input id="address1" value="Москва, красная площадь" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="address2" value="Москва, проспект ленина 20" /><input id="address3" value="Москва, Космонавтов 50" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="address4" value="Москва, гагарина 50" /> 
</div>
<div>
<button  onclick="add()" value="">добавить на карту </button>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне не введенные данные нужны, а чтобы при загрузке карты уже отображалось как минимум 5 адресов

Comment: Отредактировал ответ, для отображения 5 адресов. При добавлении метки на карту по координатам, она просто добавляется. А при добавлении по адресу - идет запрос на сервер, для получения координат, что занимает время. Если у Вас несколько адресов, заранее узнайте у них координаты, чтоб не было запроса на получение координат.

Comment: Спасибо, но Ваш ответ что-то не подходит мне. Вы отредактировали, но я не вижу всех меток (домиков) 5-и адресов. А узнавать предварительно координаты ... я ж потому и спрашиваю как чтобы не узнавать координаты, а задавать сразу эти адреса.

Comment: Функция `init` теперь добавляет 5 меток по адресам когда карта готова. Предварительно координаты можно получить на сервере, до отдачи клиенту. Или когда клиент вводит адрес.